# Angular Firestore - Display contents of sub-document array

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

**This question has a long set-up.  In the end, I'm asking for syntax coaching, and you'll see that question if you scroll to end of the set-up.**

I have a Firestore database that has a fields that contain arrays.  Here's an example:

[image]

The document itself has other fields beyond the *ingredients* element.  Here's a JSON representation of the *Congo Split* recipe you see here:

```
"congosplit": {
  "ingredients": {
    "a": {
      "ingredientAmounts": "2 Pump, 3 Pumps, 4 Pumps",
      "ingredientName": "Banana Syrup",
      "ingredientSizes": "Small, Medium, Large"
    },
    "b": {
      "ingredientAmounts": "2 Pump, 3 Pumps, 4 Pumps",
      "ingredientName": "White Chocolate",
      "ingredientSizes": "Small, Medium, Large"
    },
    "d": {
      "ingredientAmounts": "10 oz, 12 oz, 16 oz",
      "ingredientName": "Steamed Milk and Foam",
      "ingredientSizes": "Small, Medium, Large"
    }
  },
  "instructions": {
    "a": {
      "text": "Free pour milk into cup.  Top with 1/4 inch foam.  Make a circle with chocolate drizzle and use a thermometer to spread the chocolate into a flower pattern.",
      "type": "text"
    }
  },
  "name": "Congo Split",
  "temperature": "hot"
},
```

As one might infer from the structure above, both the *ingredients* and the *instructions* fields may contain more than one element... designed with *a*, *b*, and *c* in the sample below.

I have followed the sample code snippets for using Angular Firestore:

in my *recipes.service.ts* file, I have the following method that provides a real-time-updating copy of the data in *Firestore*:

```
  getRecipesFirestore() {
    this.recipesCollection = this.afs.collection('mission-cafe');
    this.recipesData = this.recipesCollection.valueChanges();
    return this.recipesData;
  }
```

in the *home.ts* file I call that method, returning the recipesData:

```
  ngOnInit() {

   [...]

    this.recipesData = this.recipesService.getRecipesFirestore();
  }
```

And the good news is I can easily show the content of *most* of this data set using an `*ngFor` in the template file:

```
  <ion-card *ngFor="let item of recipesData | async">
     <ion-title>{{item.name}}</ion-title>
  </ion-card>
```

This works for all of the keys at the top level of the document field.  But when I try to display the sub-elements of *ingredients* or *instructions* I get a `[object]` instead of the content.  It is not totally surprising.  Here's an example of what doesn't work.

```
  <ion-card *ngFor="let item of recipesData | async">
     <ion-title>{{item.name}}</ion-title>

     <div *ngFor="let ingred of item>                     < I was hoping to be able
         <ion-text>{{ingred.ingredientName}}</ion-text    < to iterate through elements
     </div>                                               <  of the ingredient array

  </ion-card>
```

**So the question:**
I cannot figure out the syntax to get to the content of the maps inside the recipe field.

I can imagine parsing the JSON (I did that when I was using the Real Time Database), but I was hoping to take advantage of the simple syntax made simple with Firestore as implied by the template file above.

Any syntax coaches out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think that Priyanka was trying to tell me is accurate, but it took me a LONG time to sort through it.  A key idea that one needs to understand is that in Firestore, The odd layers are *Collections* and the even layers are *Documents*.  Always.

However, within documents, one can have *Fields*.  Those fields can contain *Arrays* and those arrays can contain *maps*.  And of course, those maps can contain *strings*.

If you're keeping track, you have

```
Collection
  Document
    Collection
       Document   (As many as you want of the Coll/Doc layers)
         Field
            Map
               String: String
            Map
               String: String
            Array
               Map
                  String: String,
                  String: String
               Map
                (et cetera)
```

So to use my example:

In my case each *document* was a recipe that contained a *fields* of recipe components like the name and temperature.  The instructions and ingredients fields are *arrays* of *maps* that contain multi-step information, while other fields are simple things like name: `"BlendedChaiCream"`.

[image]

**So the remaining question is how to make all of this data show up in the app.**  Here's conceptually what you want to have happen.

[image]

This was the approach:

In `ngOnInit` we get the collection, and subscribe to the recipesInfo

ngOnInit() {

```
this.recipesCollection = this.afs.collection('mission-cafe');
this.recipesInfo = this.recipesCollection.snapshotChanges();

this.recipesInfo.subscribe((actionArray) => {
  this.recipesElements = actionArray.map((item) => ({
    id: item.payload.doc.id,
    ...item.payload.doc.data(),
    expanded: false
  }));
});
```

}

To explain this for newbies... `recipesElements` is the array over which the template file (the HTML file) will iterate.  So we load that up with the IDs of the recipe documents and all of the rest of the recipe documents.  That's what the spread operator `...` does.  It stands in for all of the rest of that data.  Then I add one more element `expanded` that I use later to decide whether the recipe should be expanded (open) or collapsed in an accordion display of `ion-cards`.

Then in the template file, I have this:

```
<ion-card
  (click)="expandItem($event, false, item)"  <--- use this to toggle open/closed on accordion display
  *ngFor="let item of recipesElements">
  <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>{{item.name}}
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <app-expandable expandHeight="6500px" [expanded]="item.expanded">

         [[[[insert formatting here for the display]]]]
         [[[[my formatting includes the individual fields]]]]

              item.notes
              item.image
              item.status
              and so on.

         [[[[ for instructions, I had an secondary *ngFor like this ]]]]

              <ion-item *ngFor="let ingred of item.ingredients">
         
         [[[[ and then refer to the individual ingredients as ]]]]

              <ion-grid>
                   <ion-row>
                        <ion-col> {{ingred.ingredientName}} </ion-col>
                        <ion-col> {{ingred.ingredientSizes}} </ion-col>
                        <ion-col> {{ingred.ingredientAmounts}} </ion-col>
                   </ion-row>
              <ion-grid>
          </ion-item>
     <ion-card>
```

So it is fairly straight-forward.  I just needed to understand the structure of a Firestore collection and then create an array from it over which to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, the only libraries/SDKs that allow listing the sub-collections of a document are the ones that are used in "trusted server environments" like the ones for Node.js, Java, PHP, etc. See [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document) to know more about it.

```
Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries.
```

A workaround is to store the sub-collection name(s) in a field (e.g. an array) in the document.
You can edit your recipe.services.ts function referring to this function:

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

ngOnInit() {
  ...

    this.recipesCollection =afs.collection('mission-cafe');
    this.recipesData = this.recipesCollection.valueChanges();
    return this.recipesData;                                                                
}
```

To access the subcollection of ingredients for a specific “recipe”:

```
this.subCollection = this.afs.collection('mission-cafe/'+id+'/ingredients');
```

You can collect the data in subcollections in different array and then use that in *ngFor loop in html.

Also see the Firebase documentation on following points below:

1. [Updating elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)
2. [Hierarchical model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data)

Comment: Thanks, Priyanka...  Appreciate the response.  What I'm struggling with is iterating over the returned recipesData.  I can iterate over recipesData with .forEach()... but I get stuck when trying to then iterate over the ingredientsData.  I've tried nesting a forEach and I've tried a map, but I keep striking out.  I think this is a matter of syntax.  Any thoughts?